# Limiting the number of rows in subqueries with Teradata

Tags: sql, subquery, limit, teradata

I'm new to Teradata and I'm facing a problem I didn't have with the previous database I used.
Basically, I'm trying to reduce the number of rows returned in subqueries inside a where clause. I had no problem doing this previously with the ROWNUM function.

My previous query was something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE field1 = 'foo' AND field2 in(
    SELECT field2 FROM anotherTable
    WHERE field3 = 'bar' AND ROWNUM<100);
```

Since I can't use ROWNUM in TD, I've looked for equivalent functions or at least functions that would get me where I wanted even if they were'nt exactly equivalent. 
I found and tried : ROW_NUMBER, TOP and SAMPLE.

I tried ROW_NUMBER() but Teradata doesn't allow analytic functions in WHERE clauses.
I tried TOP N but this option is not supported in a subquery.
I tried SAMPLE N but it is not supported in subqueries either.

So... I have to admit I'm a bit stuck right now and was wondering if there was any solution that would allow me to limit the number of rows returned in a subquery using Teradata and that would be pretty similar to what I did up to now?
Also, if there aren't any, how would it be possible to build the query differently to use it appropriately with Teradata?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limited usage of SAMPLE or TOP in a subquery is probably because this might be a Correlated Subquery.

But there are two workarounds.

Put SAMPLE or TOP in a Derived Table within the subquery (so this can't be correlated anymore):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE field1 = 'foo'
AND field2 IN (
     SELECT * FROM
       ( SELECT field2 FROM anotherTable -- or TOP 100
         WHERE field3 = 'bar'  SAMPLE 100
       ) AS dt
    );
```

Or rewrite it as a join to a Derived Table:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
JOIN ( SELECT DISTNCT field2 FROM anotherTable -- can't use TOP if you need DISTINCT 
         WHERE field3 = 'bar' SAMPLE 100
       ) AS dt
WHERE field1 = 'foo'
AND myTable.field2 = dt.field1;
```

TOP without ORDER BY is quite similar to ROWNUM. It's not random at all, but running it a 2nd time might still return a different result set.

SAMPLE is truly random, every time returning a different result.

ROW_NUMBER is also possible using QUALIFY instead of WHERE, but OLAP functions always need some ORDER BY, so is much more overhead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first works great! 
I also have kind of the same query but it's an UPDATE instead of a SELECT. So I tried to apply the same idea but apparently derived tables are not allowed in UPDATE statements... Any idea how to make something like that work with an UPDATE ?

Comment: The syntax for Updates using Derived Tables is UPDATE  tab FROM (SELECT ...) AS dt SET ... WHERE ...

Comment: I think that's what I tried :
`UPDATE dt
FROM ( SELECT TOP 100 * FROM myTable
WHERE field1='value' ) AS dt
SET field2 = 'foo', field3 = 'bar';`

But I still get a syntax error : "derived table not allowed for update."

Comment: You can't update the Derived Table, try **UPDATE myTable FROM ( SELECT TOP 100 * FROM myTable WHERE field1='value' ) AS dt SET field2 = 'foo', field3 = 'bar' WHERE join-between-myTable-and-dt**

Comment: Oh alright, makes much more sense in my mind now! Thanks a lot!